# Redifine a parent properties as controller into a child properties in swift

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, properties

I have 2 different containerView controllers with similar characteristics. So I decide to create a superclass controller in the storyboard and in code to manage these containerView

```
class ContainerController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
weak var listController: UIViewController?
weak var detailController: UIViewController?

let deviceIdiom = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    activateListController()        
    addListController()
}

func activateListController(){}

func addListController(){
    self.addChildViewController(listController!)
    listController?.view.frame = defineChildSize()
    self.containerView.addSubview((listController?.view)!)
    listController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
...
}
```

So, in the child controller, I need to redefine activateListController() with the specific ViewController

```
class ContainerViewController: ContainerController, ReactionViewDelegate {

var selectedProduct = String()
var selectedFunction = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {        
    super.viewDidLoad()        
}

override func activateListController(){
self.listController = listController as! ReactionViewController
self.listController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReactionController") as! ReactionViewController?
    self.listController.selectedFunction = self.selectedFunction
    self.listController?.selectedProduct = self.selectedProduct
    self.listController?.delegate = self
}}
```

But I have an error with ReactionViewController properties: "value of type viewcontroller has no member selectedFunction". The parent properties is not redifined into a child properties

I also try something like that

```
class ContainerViewController: ContainerController, ReactionViewDelegate {

var reactionViewController: ReactionViewController?
var mechanismViewController: MechanismViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    listController = reactionViewController
    detailController = mechanismViewController

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

and defining activateListController() with reactionViewController, but I had a nil exception on the method addListController() of the superclass

```
 func addListController(){
    self.addChildViewController(listController!) //nil exception
```

So, how can I well manage inherit with my containerview controller?
Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
override func activateListController(){
   let newListController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReactionController") as! ReactionViewController?
   newListController.selectedFunction = selectedFunction
   newListController.selectedProduct = selectedProduct
   newListController.delegate = self
   listController = newListController
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. I knew I was close, but I can't find the solution